# User is logged in although no users are in database and app was restarted

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, iis, simplemembership

My MVC4 application was made according to template shipped with Visual Studio 2010 and uses `SimpleMembership`.

Some minutes ago I deleted all the data from all the tables in database and restarted IIS with an iisreset command. The only thing left from previous life is a couple of cookies (`.ASPXAUTH` and `__RequestVerificationToken_L3J1bmV0c29mdC9BdXRoVGVzdA2`) in Opera browser (I didn't log out before cleanup).

Now when I try to load Home/Index, it shows me `Request.IsAuthenticated == true` and `User.Identity.Name` is available - it is the name of the last user.

The same happens after I rebuild the application.

How???!!!

Answer (score 0):

That's a bit weird, I admit. In my own experience, if you user backing the cookie is gone, an exception will be raised, but I confess, I've been running on Identity for awhile now, and don't recall if the situation was the same under ASP.NET Membership.

That said, aside from just curiosity, is there an actual issue here? Delete the .ASPXAUTH cookie and go on about your business. It's unlikely this will ever be a problem outside a development environment, since you shouldn't be deleting users in a production setting, anyhow.

Comment: Yes, there is an issue! Deleting a client-side cookie to log out isn't a right solution and is a huge security hole because server-side session isn't destroyed. I always dissuaded people from doing so, because it is a bad practice. It is not an actual logout, but only forgetting keys to the session.

Comment: In this scenario, there's nothing left of the user but the cookie. You deleted all the data in the database. If your session is in the database, it's gone too. If it's in-proc or on a SessionState server, then it might persist, but it hardly matters. The session is pruned when it times out. You can delete the cookie without issue and the associated session, if it still exists will disappear naturally. There's no danger in it temporarily existing, as there's no way to access it, now, anyways.

Comment: However, if you're that concerned about it, reset IIS or restart the SessionState server. *No* session is valid anymore, at this point, because you deleted all data that would be associated with it.

Comment: Ok, the question remains: Where it all comes from when everything is deleted?